# mail() function not working on php

Tags: php, debugging, email

The `mail($to, $subject, $message, $from);` function isn't working in the code below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
       </head>
       <body>
        <?php
         if ($_POST['Gender'] = 'M') {
          $prefix = 'Mr.';
         }else if($_POST['Gender'] = 'F') {
          $prefix = 'Miss/ Mrs.';
         }

         $start1 = "The message: " . $_POST['Subject'] . "/n Was sent to you at " . date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); 
         $sender = "By: " .  $prefix . "  " . $_POST['Name'];
         $content = "The message : /n /n" . $_POST['Massage'];
         $sufix = "To reply to this email:  " . $_POST['Email'];
         $from = $_POST['Email'];

         $to = "info@mybataba.com";
         $subject = "You have a new massage on mybataba.com" . $_POST['Subject'];
         $message = $start1 . $sender . $content . $sufix

         mail ($to, $subject, $message, $from);  
        ?>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: What happens when it runs ? what errors are you getting ? have you configured anything to get this working ? ie smtp host ?

Comment: it just tells me theres a problem on line 27 (both on dreamweaver & http://ideone.com/Xjopo)

Comment: Which OS are you using ? and whats line 27 ?

Comment: what line is line 27 (no line numbers here on SO), also turn on error reporting etc and see what that says when you try executing the script?

Comment: try removing the space between mail and the paran (.  `mail($to, $subject, $message, $from);` unless that's just a copy/paste issue.

Comment: @Robert that kind of whitespace does not matter in PHP http://codepad.viper-7.com/3nioKk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have a programming issue (errors will be thrown)

**OR**

You need to confirm your mail settings are correct in `PHP.INI`, it comes down to having your server software configured to SEND OUT MAIL, vs SENDING IN PHP.

Once you make sure your server is configured properly your PHP `mail()` will work

**EDIT**

Just noticed too that you are missing a `;` on this line:

```
$message = $start1 . $sender . $content . $sufix
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$message = $start1 . $sender . $content . $sufix
```

should be

```
$message = $start1 . $sender . $content . $sufix;
```

Thats why you receive the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   /home/R6iJfd/prog.php on line 27

Comment: Thanks a lot... Its annoying how small staff like that can cause so much trouble on php...

Answer (score 1):

The `$from` is supposed to be a header. So, you need to write this :

```
$from = 'From: '.$_POST['Email'];
```

You have another problem, but it's not related with the mail:

```
if ($_POST['Gender'] = 'M') {
```

Should be :

```
if ($_POST['Gender'] == 'M') {
```